# 3D View not showing ortho view even when it says it is?

Tags: 3d-view

New here, about 6 mos on Blender, mostly in 2.78 and 2.79... so I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

I don't know how to describe this... but Blender's lying to me. I'm trying to go to top orthographic view for a model, but even though I'm hitting 9 on the numpad, and it's showing the right thing in the upper left corner of 3d view, but this ISN'T orthogonal view.

I'm COMPLETELY confused at this point and don't know how to begin troubleshooting except a reinstall... Running 2.79, nothing that SHOULD affect this as far as addons (that I know of).

http://i1160.photobucket.com/albums/q486/BeyondNERVA/Ortho%20problem_zpslfi8azsd.jpg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Apl0.jpg)
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Apl0.jpg)

Comment: For clarification, that's IMMEDIATELY after hitting 9 on the numpad... repeated pressing of 9 doesn't change the issue, but if an object isn't selevted it shifts the grid outside the viewport so I can't see the model or the origin. shift+cmb to re-center leaves it at apparently the same angle,but a few grid dimensions away from being seen. That may help...

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what numpad 9 does, but for the 3 main views there is numpad 1,3 and 7 (or ctrl 1,3 and 7) for the reverse direction. Numpad 9 does not forcibly align the view to one of the global main axis.

Another possibility would have been, if you had changed the "Global" option in the transform orientation pane, but it looks fine on your screenshot.

[image: Numpad functions]

Comment: Wow... I typoed twice. That's a way to make a good impression. ;P

It would show side orthos, but not top, even when I hit the correct button (7). I'm booting it up again today after having the computer shut down. Maybe the 4th time is a charm.

Comment: could you upload your blendfile at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there was an update for Blender that I didn't have during my searches, so just installed the new version and it's now behaving normally. No clue WHAT the problem was, but it's gone now!